# Delete an object from an Array of object from mongodb using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

tags": [{"assigned_by": "XXXX",
"tag": {"permissions": {"public": false, "roles": ["XXX","XXX"],"self": false},  "models": [ "COMMENTS"],"name": "IN_REVIEW","created_at": {"$date": {            "$numberLong": "1656396397488"}}},"created_at": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1656396444394"       }}}]

```
How do I delete the 0th element of this array of objects in node-js :
Tried:
  editedComment.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $pull: { 'comment.tags' : { 'tag':  { name: 'IN_REVIEW' } } }})
```

not working tag is not getting deleted.
Please let me know how to delete it.

Comment: what mongo client are you using?

Comment: Does your document really contains `comment` with it containing a `tags` array? You are trying to update `comment.tags` but the `comment.tags` doesn't exist in the attached document.

Comment: Yes tags is  inside the comments document like a array of object embedded inside comment document. when i console.log comment.tags[0].tag.name i get the response in_review but deleting it was not possible

Comment: Using mongoose.